# Window without borders with transparency to display an image

Tags: c#, image, transparency

ok heres my question:

Is there any possibility to create a window in C# without border and menu bar?
U can imagine my idea like a little old school ms-word helper.

i found something similar in c++:

[transparency layered window white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449491/transparency-layered-window-white)

Thanks in advance!:D

Comment: By "old school ms-word helper" are you referring to the Office Assistant/MSAgent? http://i.imgur.com/ySKuQOM.jpg

Comment: Thank you all for your help!
Yes i mean this little MsAgent... ^^
thanks for the link Alexander!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Form Border Style = None.